# How to send request to proxy pass url based on server name in nginx?

Tags: nginx

I have subdomains a.domain.com and b.domain.com. Below is my configuration:

```
server {
 listen 80;
 server_name a.domain.com b.domain.com;

 location / {
   .
   .
   .
   proxy_pass http://example.com/$server_name/;
 }
}
```

This is giving error like

> "no resolver defined to resolve http://example.com/..."

Is it possible to send proxy pass url based on server name or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to proxy requests to example.com. But you haven't defined example.com as an [`upstream`](http://nginx.org/r/upstream), so nginx treats it as a hostname to look up and connect to. But you don't have a DNS [`resolver`](http://nginx.org/r/resolver) defined anywhere.

To fix the problem, do one of those two things.